# Unresolved variable $ jquery + reactJS

Tags: jquery, reactjs, variables

I started a react project and wanted to add jQuery to my project. I added this in my index.html head

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I've also added this in my package.json

```
"env": {
    "browser": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "es6": true,
    "jquery": true
  }
```

When I run my app its gives an error, because $.getJSON isn't recognised, so jQuery isn't working? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It probably means the code calling `$.getJSON` is called before jquery script is loaded.

If you use reactjs, you probably use a module bundler like webpack or browserify. Then you can install jquery as a module with `npm install jquery`. So in the components where jquery is needed, you can do `$ = require("jquery")` or `import {$} from "jquery"`